# Ubuntu Software Center Infinite Loading

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, skype, gtk

I JUST downloaded Ubuntu for the first time ever after my MBR got infected. And I went into the Ubuntu Software Center and tried to search for "Skype", it was infinitely loading, everything but the "All" sector has eternal loading, how can I fix this? When I press a category it only shows three dots in rectangles?

I also tried to launch USC through the terminal, it worked but it seemed to be an older version. I got this when I launched it through the terminal:

```
isse@isse-Lenovo-B50-10:~$ sudo software-center
[sudo] password for isse: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for isse: 
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/purchaseview.py:29: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as webkit
2017-01-09 19:50:18,106 - softwarecenter.backend.zeitgeist_logger - WARNING - Support for Zeitgeist disabled
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/symbolic_icons.py:23: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, PangoCairo
2017-01-09 19:50:18,203 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2017-01-09 19:50:18,989 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2017-01-09 19:50:19,092 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2017-01-09 19:50:19,097 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2017-01-09 19:50:19,167 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2017-01-09 19:50:20,410 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py:29: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gst
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 123 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 71 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
2017-01-09 19:50:25,866 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
2017-01-09 19:50:27,804 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

Comment: Added an answer.  Might just need to enable the partner repositories.

Comment: Why are you starting `software-center` as super-user? It will ask you for authentication when necessary. Also, if you're running graphical applications as super-user at all please use `gksudo` instead of `sudo` or you are likely to run into file access permission issue later.

Comment: If you just installed Ubuntu, please update the package list (`sudo apt update`), perform a full upgrade (`sudo apt full-upgrade`) and try again. If you run into errors again, please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* program output.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Xubuntu yesterday and it was like that, too.
Update and reboot solved the problem.

To Update:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Skype should be able to be installed directly from the repositories that Ubuntu uses.

Checking where Skype comes from, it looks as though it comes from the `Partner` repositories.  So those need to be enabled.

Since I have it installed, I ran `apt-cache` to get the repository that it came from.

```
~$ apt-cache showpkg skype
Package: skype
Versions: 
4.3.0.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_partner_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
```

As you can see partner is part of the name.

Go to Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software tab.

[image]

After the partner boxes are selected (which is the top 2 on my list), click Close, then it should reload the cache.

If they don't exist, Click on Add, and add these two lines in (add them one by one):

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

[image]

When you close it, it should update the cache.

Now, you should be able to install Skype from the command line:

```
sudo apt install skype
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That command does not work :/ `isse@isse-Lenovo-B50-10:~$ apt-cache showpkg skype
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
`

Comment: @user7312963 I was doing that command to show where it came from.  I have Skype installed on my system and just tested all of this out.  It won't work on yours until you get Skype installed.

Comment: Alright but I have nothing in 'Other Software'.  @Terrance

Comment: @user7312963 Edited to show how to add them to it.

Comment: `isse@isse-Lenovo-B50-10:~$ sudo apt install skype
[sudo] password for isse: 
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.`

Comment: Alright, I think it was fixed. Thanks alot @Terrance !